# Python IO matching strings from different files

Tags: python, dictionary, io, text-files, counting

Kind of a python newbie here, so could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: 
Problem is:
unexpected output... the frequency for some lines is more than 100, while I only have 10 files in path and each file only has unique lines.

Here's the basic algorithm:

- Read a REF file
- For each files (x) in path, do the following:
- Compare each line in x with each line in REF, then:
- if both lines match then increment the line count(frequency) by 1.
- if this line doesn't exist in REF then, add this line to output and set frequency to 0.

  ```
  import os
  from itertools import izip

  path = "./logs"

  rankdict = {}
  with open('REF.out', 'r') as f:
          for line in f:
                  rankdict[line.strip()]= int(0)

  for d in os.listdir(path):
          pd = os.path.join(path, d)
          with open(pd, 'r') as currentFile:
                  for line in izip(currentFile):
                          linex = str(line).strip()
                          if linex not in rankdict:
                                  rankdict.update({linex: int(0)})
                          else:
                                  rankdict[linex] +=1
  ```

Comment: What's not working? Errors? Unexpected output?

Comment: oh sorry, yes, unexpected output... the frequency for some lines is more than 100, while I only have 10 files in path and each file only has unique lines.

Comment: Why `izip(currentFile)` and not just `currentFile` in that `for` loop?

Comment: Good question. Now that I see it, I have no idea why I did that. Still doesn't fix the problem though.

Comment: ...and for general tidiness, replace `int(0)` with `0`.

Comment: and `rankdict.update({linex: int(0)})` with `rankdict[linex] = 0`. and `linex = str(line).strip()` with `linex = line.strip()`.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you again. Problem's still there though.